# Merging different regions at a same time

Tags: excel

If A1 having the name `suresh` and A2 and A3 also having the same name `suresh` and A4 having the name `ramesh` and A5,A6,A7 and A8 having the name `ramesh`.

Now I need to merge at a time for A1,A2,A3 as `suresh` and A4,A5,A6,A7,A8 as `ramesh` and vice versa for other columns for other different names.

Comment: Select the cells you want to merge and merge them using `Format Cells` :)

Comment: If I need to merge A1, A2,A3,A4 with the same name suresh then I can select them and merge together. But here A1, A2, A3 ,A4  as suresh and A5,A6,A7,A8 as ramesh. Now I nedd to merge at the same time as A1,A2,A3,A4 as suresh and remaning A5,A6,A7,A8 as ramesh at single strecth

Comment: at a single stretch? What does that mean? (I'm probably tired) Is it you want to merge all `A1:A8` in a single merge but in a way that "suresh" appears on the left and "ramesh" on the right?

Comment: No man. Actually a1 cell as suresh and a2 cell as suresh and a3 as suresh. if i need to merge i want to selcet a1,a2,a3 and select merge. and now a4 as ramesh , a5 as ramesh and a6 as ramesh. need to select a4, a5 and a6  and need to merge. I am asking whether we can do these 2 kind of merge at a same time because the scenario is repeating till a455 with different names. I think I have explained you clearly.

Comment: Ah ok. As far as I know, this is not possible. You can possibly try to automate the process with some VBA.

Comment: Okay. Anyway thanks for valuable reply.

Comment: If you can go for VBA solution see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637698/how-to-merge-cells-based-on-similar-values-excel-2010)

Comment: @A.S.H it is possible see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the `Merge Cells` feature instead of the `Merge & Center` feature.

Therefore select A1 to A3 by clicking to A1 and dragging to A3 (**not** by clicking each cell itself)! And after that keep holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and select A4 to A8 by clicking to A4 and dragging to A8. Then select `Merge Cells` from the merge menu.

You will end up with 2 cells:

- A1 to A3
- A4 to A8

Comment: Good tip. it works. I even unifies the value. For completeness, user needs to keep `Ctrl` before selecting the other area to merge. In fact, you are selecting a multi-area range then merging which merges each area separately. This is how it worked for me.

Comment: @A.S.H Of course! I improved my answer ;) I assumed that everyone knew how to muli select but now it's clear.