# How to merge same years together

Tags: vba, excel

I want to take 2 dates from sheet 1 and generate that date range in sheet 2 in terms of months and years. I have a code that does this but I encounter a few problems which I'll explain later. [This is what my code does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqRZ1.png) (assuming the 2 dates in sheet 1 are oct-17 and mar-18 in MM-YY format).

1. My main question is, how do I get the same years to merge together? [I want it to look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJDVQ.png)
2. The first problem I encounter is that I have to run the macro twice for the years format to change. What can I do to fix this?
3. The second problem is that some times some of the months will not display correctly and will instead show "########" as shown in the first attached picture. I notice this only happens with custom date formats. Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

I would really appreciate any help I can get. The following is my code

```
Sub macro3Planning()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws2.Range("B3").Offset(3, 8)

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim NoDays As Integer  

StartDate = ws1.Range("D6").Value
EndDate = ws1.Range("D7").Value
NoDays = EndDate - StartDate + 1

'Generates months
With rng
    .Value = StartDate
    .Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
    xlMonth, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False       
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .NumberFormat = "mmm"
    .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
End With

Set rng = rng.Offset(-1)

'Generates year
With rng
    .Value = StartDate
    .Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
    xlMonth, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False       
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy"
    .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
End With

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

3 . This happens because the column is not wide enough. I changed the format to "mmm" from "mmmm" so that the resulting months are always short enough to fit inside the column. Thanks @ClementB and @PalimPalim!

1 . I managed to get and modify a code to merge the cells with matching contents from [How to merge cells based on similar values - Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637698/how-to-merge-cells-based-on-similar-values-excel-2010). Now all I need is to extract the years from the date, since I dim'd the years as date, so the actual values behind those 2017s and 2018s are 10/1/2017, 11/1/2017 and so on. Hence, I cant use the merge similar cells macro yet.

I'm thinking of using DatePart("yyyy") with a loop for all the years but I am not sure how as I am still new to excel vb. Please assist.

Comment: 1) You just need to merge the years with this : Range("J5:L5").Merge  . To know you need to stop at L5, you just need to iterate before with a simple loop.        
2) Use CDate(Format(target.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"))       
3) I'm pretty sure it's because the columns are not big enough

Comment: your second problem happens because the column is not wide enough. If you change the width of column K for example, the date should be clearly visible.

Comment: Pretty much the exact same question was asked earlier today, here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387798/excel-vba-merging-a-range-inside-a-loop

Comment: Thank you clementB and PalimPalim for answering my question no.3. I didnt realise the solution was that simple!
Regarding the link from @Rik Sportel,  my range of years are actually dates but formatted to only show YYYY. So the real value is still in date, for example, 10/1/2017, 11/1/2017 and so on.

Comment: as a side note, ### happens only for numeric values. You can use `.Text` instead of `.Value` to get the text displayed in the cell instead of the cell value

Comment: Noted. Thanks @Slai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just called the following macro right at the end of the above code. The macro is to extract years from the date and then to merge every cell with the same years together. With this, I managed to solve my question 1 and 2. Seems like a long code for just a simple task.

```
Sub mergesameyears()

Dim lastCol As Integer
lastCol = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Dim tosubtract As Integer
'9 is the column J number
tosubtract = 9

'Number of generated years
Dim noyears As Integer
noyears = lastCol - tosubtract

Dim selectyear As Integer

'Set rng to J5 which is first generated year
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("J5")

Dim yearvalue As Integer
Dim asd As Long

For selectyear = 1 To noyears Step 1
    asd = rng.Value
    yearvalue = DatePart("yyyy", asd)
    rng.Clear
    rng.Value = yearvalue
    Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
Next selectyear

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim lastColumn As Range
Set lastColumn = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,     Searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

Dim mergesame As Range, cell As Range
Set mergesame = Range("J5", lastColumn.Offset(-1))

Merge:
    For Each cell In mergesame
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False     Then
            With Range(cell, cell.Offset(, 1))
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            End With
            GoTo Merge
        End If
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```